# OverlayLayout doesn't seem to be Layering

Tags: java, swing, layout, overlay

I'm attempting to use an OverlayLayout to place a small bit of text in line with the top tabs of a JTabbedPane, however it doesn't seem to work.

As a note I was using a JLayeredPane, however I need the TabbedPane to fill the parent component, and it didn't seem like it would work without some finagling.

Anyway it seems that when you leave the alignments alone the behavior works as expected (the button floats over the background). However when using any sort of alignment (it's my understanding that this is how you set position with this layout manager), it will shrink the background to the edge of where the button should be.

Here's some sample code.

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        Container c = frame.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(c));

        JButton button = new JButton("Test");
        JPanel background = new JPanel();
        background.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
        background.setSize(500, 500);
        // toggle the following between 0 and 100 to see the described behavior
        background.setAlignmentX(100);

        frame.add(background);
        frame.add(button);

        frame.pack();
        frame.setSize(800, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: *"Any suggestions would be appreciated."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: *"attempting to use an OverlayLayout to place a small bit of text in line with the top tabs of a JTabbedPane"* Why?  What is the text & how does it relate to the tab(s)?

Comment: I'll revise my question. Thanks. The lead tab is a graphic, the text is meant to show the current mouse coordinates or possibly other relevant information. The customer asked that it be there (it does look nice)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the method `setGlassPane` for put a pane over other in a frame. Check in http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/rootpane.html

Comment: I love GlassPane, simple without any of performance issue but sometimes crazy +1

Answer (score 2):

- mistake is using setBound() where is useless and contraproductive for this LayoutManager
- use [implemented methods in the API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/OverlayLayout.html) about `setMaximumSize()`
- [then there no issue](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/OverlayLayoutforlayoutmanagementofcomponentsthatlieontopofoneanother.htm)

---

if you want to really to create JComponents that overlay another you have look at

- JLayeredPane --> outdated and you can use only up to 6.th LayeredPanes
- JXLayer for Java6 or direct implementations as JLayer in Java7
- for simple overlay you can use GlassPane too,

Comment: Whoops the setBounds() call snuck in from a previous experiment. Removed it. I'm not entirely sure how setMaximumSize will help with the OverlayLayout issue. The problem is that the components seem to be behaving as if I was using a regular layout manager (they're not layering over top of each other). I'll investigate the other suggestions though. Thanks.

Comment: You can see in _A Visual Guide to Layout Managers_  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html